# How to count same values of number in column using matlab

Tags: matlab, count

So here's my problem i want to count the numbers of same values in a column, this my data:

```
a   b   d
2   1   5
1   3   10
1   -2  5
0   5   25
5   0   25
1   1   2
-1  -1  2
```

i want to count the same values of d (where d = a^2 + b^2), so this is the output i want:

```
a   b   d   count
2   1   5   2
1   3   10  1
0   5   25  2
1   1   2   2
```

so as you can see, only positive combinations of a and b displayed. so how can i do that? thanks.

Comment: Is your data a matrix or a `table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is a *matrix*, here's an [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)-based approach. Note this doesn't address the requirement "only positive combinations of *a* and *b* displayed".

```
M = [2   1   5
     1   3   10
     1   -2  5
     0   5   25
     5   0   25
     1   1   2
     -1  -1  2]; %// data
[~, jj, kk] = unique(M(:,3),'stable');
s = accumarray(kk,1);
result = [M(jj,:) s];
```

Comment: Did you see my comment that this doesn't address the requirement "only positive combinations of a and b displayed"? Maybe the other answer does?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input data to be stored in a 2D array, this could be one approach -

```
%// Input
A =[
    2   1   5
    1   3   10
    1   -2  5
    0   5   25
    5   0   25
    1   1   2
    -1  -1  2]

[unqcol3,unqidx,allidx] = unique(A(:,3),'stable')
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,A(:,3),unqcol3.'),1)  %//'
out =[A(unqidx,:) counts(:)]
```

You can also get the counts with `histc` -

```
counts = histc(allidx,1:max(allidx))
```

---

**Note on positive combinations of `a` and `b`:** If you are looking to have positive combinations of `A` and `B`, you can select only those rows from `A` that fulfill this requirement and save back into `A` as a pre-processing step -

```
A = A(all(A(:,1:2)>=0,2),:)
```

Comment: what is 'stable' for?

Comment: @nobel To keep the order as it is, because without it, `unique` will sort the data.

Comment: @LuisMendo Well, you know me!! ;)

Comment: Does this fulfill the requirement "only positive combinations of a and b displayed"? (my answer doesn't)

Comment: @LuisMendo Ops didn't notice that requirement. How about a mask at the end?

Comment: @Divakar Anyway, the OP seems to be happy without that